# How to interpolate this?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a problem with interpolating.

the plot of the points is
[here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSNIy.png)

If we zoom in , the plot looks something like this 
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpRlF.png)

I do not know how to use the Matlab interp1 function to interpolate this.

**Explanation:**

This is a space time diagram, i.e. the x axis is the space and the y-axis is the time.

Hence, the structure of the vectors x and y is as follows:

The vector y is defined as

> > y=(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,...,2500,2500)

and the x-vector contains (pairwise) the positions, i.e.

`x(i)` and `x(i+1)` are the different positions at time `y(i)=y(i+1)`.

I think the problem maybe is that at different times, we have the same points as can be seen in the zoomed in picture above.

How many time-steps the x-values remain the same differs, sometimes they remain the same for 3 time-steps, sometimes even for 4 time-steps, sometimes only for 2 time-steps.

Comment: Are you trying to use MATLAB's `interp1`?

Comment: Yes, right. But I guess it does not work if we have the same x-values for different y-values.

Comment: You could draw a line that passes through the center of all your small segments (If that has any physical meaning)

Comment: It depends strongly on what you are simulating though. Taking the min or the max of these values is as pertinent without more insight on what you are trying to simulate

Comment: I can suggest you a Least Squares solution (Though it a bit tricky in this case). Would you like that? Or the solution from @excaza is good enough?

Comment: I used unique() and it worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`acccumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to perform some operation on the values in `Y` that correspond to each unique value of `X`.

Using some example data:

```
x = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8];
y = 1:length(x);
```

We get something like the following:

[image: raw]

Now use `accumarray` to perform some calculation on each cluster:

```
clusteravg = accumarray(x', y, [], @mean);
clustermax = accumarray(x', y, [], @max);
clustermin = accumarray(x', y, [], @min);
```

The first input to `accumarray` is an array of subscripts, the second input is an array of values that correspond to those subscripts. `accumarray` collects all of the elements of the second input that share the same subscript (first input) and performs the specified calculation on them. Here I've calculated the average, max, and min for each cluster of values:

[image: yay]

Yay